# Systemd service script not logging during shutdown

Tags: scripts, network-manager, services, systemd, rsyslog

**Background**

NetworkManager doesn't run dispatcher.d/pre-down.d scripts, so I have created a systemd-service script. It is working well during startup and shutdown, but during shutdown it doesn't write to syslog. The file /etc/iptables.rules is updated during shutdown, but nothing is logged to /var/log/syslog.

From the terminal running ...

```
systemctl restart network-down
```

... writes information to syslog. But not during system reboot.

**Question**

Is there something missing in my service-script?

**Script: /etc/systemd/system/network-down.service:**

```
[Unit]
Description=Firewall Iptables Save
Wants=network-online.target
After=network.target network-online.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/true
ExecStop=/bin/bash /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/pre-down.d/01-firewall-pre-down network pre-down
RemainAfterExit=yes
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
SyslogIdentifier=Firewall Iptables Save

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**Script: 01-firewall-pre-down:**

```
if [ -x /usr/bin/logger ]; then
            LOGGER="/usr/bin/logger -s -p daemon.info -t FirewallHandler[PREDOWN]"
    else
            LOGGER=echo
    fi

case "$2" in

        pre-up)
                if [ ! -r /etc/iptables.rules ]; then
                        ${LOGGER} "No iptables rules exist to restore."
                        return
                fi
                if [ ! -x /sbin/iptables-restore ]; then
                        ${LOGGER} "No program exists to restore iptables rules."
                        return
                fi
                ${LOGGER} "Restoring iptables rules (pre-up)"
                /sbin/iptables-restore -c < /etc/iptables.rules
                ;;
        pre-down)
                if [ ! -x /sbin/iptables-save ]; then
                        ${LOGGER} "No program exists to save iptables rules."
                        return
                fi
                ${LOGGER} "Saving iptables rules. (pre-down)"
                /sbin/iptables-save -c > /etc/iptables.rules
                ;;
        *)
                 ${LOGGER} "Nothing to do for case: ($2)"
                ;;
esac
```

Comment: Maybe `rsyslogd` is stopped before your script is run? You are usig `syslog`as your output/error facility.

Comment: @XubuntuLover Can you please add that edit as an answer rather than just saying solved

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
After=network.target network-online.target
```

to:

```
After=network.target network-online.target rsyslog.service
```

Now it should be logging!